# Version control on Entity form type submissions

Tags: nodes, entities, version-control

A project collecting data from multiple entity forms was handed over to me. My client requested the implementation of a review mechanism for the data that are stored in entity form submissions.

The reviewers should have the ability to edit the submissions while they are keeping the initial content intact. The features extend to comparison between the various versions of the submission along with comments that can be attached to each version explaining the scope of the changes.

Pretty much the exact functionality that [Node revisions](https://www.drupal.org/node/320614) are covering at the moment.

Unfortunately I just discovered that revisions are not available for entityform submissions ([Add revision support to submissions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2021009)) leading me to a dead end.

So, I seek some experienced guidance if there is a workaround to this, that I'm unable to see.

- Could I create this versioning system somehow with the current data
  structure?
- Would it be able to migrate the data collected from form submissions to content type nodes so that I can use their revision framework (along with Diff and Node Compare modules)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to hack data out of an Entity form seems to make things unnecessarily more complicated, so I decided to redesign the whole form as a content type create form, while using [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) fields to link the various instances.